# Magento 2: Static file path is wrong, should be pub/static/.... instead of static/

Tags: ubuntu, magento, magento2, magento2.4

So i just installed magento2 on my linux localhost using php 8.2 and magento 2.4 on ubuntu.

but once i load it up there is no css or js, and the filepaths to said stuff is wrong (see images)

[image: Errors]

i have my rewrite module set up and installed, but maybe its just not working?
the files are definitely there, but the path its trying to look in is slightly off, it should look in: magento/pub/static/...
not: magento/static/...

what can i do to fix this? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few steps you can take to fix the problem:

1. Make sure that you have configured the base URL correctly in Magento.You can do this by using the following command:

`bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url="http://your-domain.com/"`

2. Check if Apache or Nginx settings are correct. Make sure that the virtual host or server configuration is correctly configured for Magento 2 and points to the correct directory.
   If you need to search the `magento/pub/static/` , you can
   change the DocumentRoot value in the host configuration settings.
   Example: `DocumentRoot /var/www/{host}/magento/pub`
3. Check that the permissions settings for Magento files and directories are correct. Make sure that you have the correct read and write permissions for the pub/static directory and its subdirectories.
4. Regenerate Magento static files.

`bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: I Figured it out, my base URL was simply http://localhost/magento/

but when i put /pub/ after it, it worked. for some reason without that it wanted to route all the static files to my magento root folder, instead of magento/pub/

Thanks anyway for your reply!